# Build and deploy a Zend Framework PHP application in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, zend-framework2, phplint

I'm setting up a jenkins job to build and deploy a Zend Framework 2 php application.
In my ant build script I've defined a lint job for validating php files.

The build job failed because lint detected an error in a ZF2 library file.

This is the output generated by lint:

```
[apply] PHP Fatal error:  Constructor Zend\Captcha\Factory::factory() cannot be static in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/XXX/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Captcha/Factory.php on line 90
[apply] Errors parsing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/XXX/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Captcha/Factory.php
```

Does anybody know why the validation of `Zend/Captcha/Factory.php fails` ?

The ANT Task looks like this:

```
    <target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <apply executable="php" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="-l" />

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/tests">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>
  </apply>
 </target>
```

Comment: Your question would be more useful for future visitors if you posted the definition of the job. I don't know whether I would make a difference in anyone's ability to answer the question (which is the reason I haven't downvoted this) but generally just posting an error message is not very helpful.

Comment: What version of php do you use? Normally there is no problem with a static factory method (there is no constructor whatsoever). The latest tag (2.0.3) looks like this and is linted on my machine (php 5.3.14) fine: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7f49f1e1a22994ea5d7cf4da1c49119df274b99d/library/Zend/Captcha/Factory.php#L20

Comment: @Jurian Sluiman: Thanks for your response.
I'm using PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18 with Suhosin-Patch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is because Zend Framework requires php 5.3.3 or later. Since your Jenkins box uses 5.3.2, this give a variety of problems. One of them is apparently the error you have now.

I think you haven't noticed the error before because on the development system you have a 5.3.3+ install. Try to update your testing environment to a newer version of php, that will remove this particular problem.

**Update**

To clarify my answer a bit, there is one backwards compatibility break in php 5.3.3 which comes back in your environment. Check [this changelog](http://nl.php.net/releases/5_3_3.php) and particularly this statement:

> **Backwards incompatible change:**
>
> Methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method in PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
?>
```

> There is no impact on migration from 5.2.x because namespaces were only introduced in PHP 5.3.

In the case of `Zend\Captcha\Factory`, there is a method `factory()` which is static so you can call `Zend\Captcha\Factory::factory()`. On php 4 and 5 up to 5.3.2, this method is **also** parsed as the constructor for the factory. And constructors cannot be static.

A linter will give you a fatal error for this case.

Comment: @MadeOfSport see my update, I showed you also the reason why a php 5.3.2 would not work in this case.